# Displaying isolated points using pm3d Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am plotting 3D histograms using pm3d in Gnuplot. Data is provided below. The sequence of steps in Gnuplot are:

```
set view map
splot 'test.dat' u 1:2:(log($3)) with pm3d t " ", 'test.dat' u 1:2:(log($3)) t " "
```

as you can see in this figure:

[image]

some data points are not plotted with pm3d, I think because the lack of coordination with neighboring points. I wonder if there is a way to explicitly plot these non-well coordinated points in Gnuplot using pm3d.

Note: The "plot with images" doesn't work in my case, because the data set I have is much more larger than this simple example and the plot looks like fragmented squares.

Thanks.

Data:

```
   1           1           1
   1           2           0
   1           3           0
   1           4           0
   1           5           0
   1           6           0
   1           7           0
   1           8           0

   2           1           0
   2           2           0
   2           3           1
   2           4           2
   2           5           3
   2           6           0
   2           7           0
   2           8           0

   3           1           0
   3           2           0
   3           3           2
   3           4          10
   3           5          15
   3           6           2
   3           7           0
   3           8           0

   4           1           0
   4           2           0
   4           3           0
   4           4           5
   4           5           2
   4           6           1
   4           7           0
   4           8           0

   5           1           0
   5           2           0
   5           3           0
   5           4           3
   5           5           2
   5           6           0
   5           7           0
   5           8           0

   6           1           0
   6           2           0
   6           3           0
   6           4           2
   6           5           0
   6           6           0
   6           7           1
   6           8           0

   7           1           0
   7           2           0
   7           3           0
   7           4           0
   7           5           0
   7           6           0
   7           7           0
   7           8           0

   8           1           0
   8           2           0
   8           3           0
   8           4           0
   8           5           0
   8           6           0
   8           7           1.1
   8           8           0
```

Comment: Can you post your larger dataset, and how your current output looks like? Also, have a look at your previous question, and consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: I don't understand, why plot with images doesn't work, because you cannot interpolate between numbers and NaN, anyway. Or what would you expect?